# Auto update does not respect changed projects

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I am setting up '**spring-cloud-config-monitor**' so when I get a gitlab webhook it will automatically update my projects.

I am testing with two projects '**monitoring-service**' and '**config-server**', but when a push callback arrives in gitlab warning that a file has changed in the '**monitoring-service**' project '**config-server**' is refreshing can you also avoid this behavior?

Comment: I think it is happening because of how the spring-cloud-bus works. The local service gets the event regardless, there is an open issue in bus for this. Extracting monitor to its own service would mitigate this.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for the answer, I will look into this issue and see if I can contribute.